# Display li content over image

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS, I have a header with a menu list and an image just below the header.

When I hover on Gallery within menu bar, it displaces the image below by the height of hovered block.Is there any way to make the content overlap on the image rather than displacing it.

```
<header class="container">
    <h1>First <br/> Website</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav group">
            <li><a href="" title="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Gallery</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" title=""><span>Images</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="" title=""><span>Videos<span></a></li>
                <li><a href="" title=""><span>Animations<span></a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</header><!-- /header -->

<section class="container img" id="corousel">
    <img src="trolltunga.jpg" alt="Test Image">
</section>

<footer class="container">
    More to come...
</footer>
```

Here is a fiddle to my code, https://jsfiddle.net/khushboo_sangal/5xLs5odu/

Comment: .nav li ul {position:absolute;}

Comment: Notice that the fiddle has some HTML errors (marked red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the dropdown menu out of the document flow by positioning it `absolute`. Just make sure to set it's parent's position to `relative`.

```
.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5xLs5odu/2/

You also had some unclosed `<span />` tags in your nested ul. Thanks @vals for pointing this out:

```
<li><a href="" title=""><span>Videos</span></a></li>
<li><a href="" title=""><span>Animations</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Notice that the fiddle has some errors in the HTML (marked red)

Comment: @vals Thanks for pointing that out. It looked like JSFiddle was complaining due to some unclosed `span` tags (though it had no affect on the original problem).  Fixed in the new fiddle.